# Cloudwatch metrics count not increasing for aws lambda integrated with micrometer

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, micrometer

I am working on integrating micrometer cloudwatch library in aws lambda function.
I am creating meter registry as below -

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public CloudWatchAsyncClient cloudWatchAsyncClient() {
    return CloudWatchAsyncClient.builder().region(Region.of("us-east-1")).build();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public MeterRegistry getMeterRegistry(CloudWatchAsyncClient cloudWatchAsyncClient) {
    CloudWatchConfig cloudWatchConfig = setupCloudWatchConfig();
    return new CloudWatchMeterRegistry(cloudWatchConfig, Clock.SYSTEM, cloudWatchAsyncClient);
}

private CloudWatchConfig setupCloudWatchConfig() {
    return new CloudWatchConfig() {

        private final Map<String, String> configuration =
                Map.of(
                        "cloudwatch.namespace",
                        "service-name",
                        "cloudwatch.step",
                        Duration.ofMinutes(1).toString());

        @Override
        public String get(String key) {
            return configuration.get(key);
        }
    };
}
```

2. In case of important events, I am incrementing counters as -

> meterRegistry.counter("counterName").increment();

After running lambda with this code, I am able to see counterName appearing in cloudwatch. However count for the same is always 0.

I verified that lambda role has PutMetricData permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening, as lambda was running for 15 seconds and Cloudwatch config was set to publish metrics every 1 minute. So lambda was exiting before metrics were getting published.

After setting that value to a lesser value, metrics started appearing.